# Rails 4 - How to render JSON regardless of requested format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I'd like a Rails controller (all of them, actually, it's an API) to render JSON always always.

I don't want Rails to return "route not found", or try and fail to find an HTML template, or return 406. I just want it to automatically and always render JSON, e.g. from a RABL or JBuilder view.

Is this possible? Related questions seem to have answers that have the aforementioned downsides.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can add a `before_filter` in your controller to set the request format to `json`:

```
# app/controllers/foos_controller.rb

before_action :set_default_response_format

protected

def set_default_response_format
  request.format = :json
end
```

This will set all response format to `json`.  If you want to allow other formats, you could check for the presence of `format` parameter when setting `request.format`, for e.g:

```
def set_default_response_format
  request.format = :json unless params[:format]
end
```

Comment: Naturally, this can be placed in `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` to have an application-wide effect (strictly if your app is an API)

Comment: FWIW, I just tried this solution in Rails 5 (with html format, vs json) and Rails wouldn't take `:html`, it needed `'html'` as a string. Not sure why it wouldn't accept a symbol for `request.format`, but once I changed it to `'html'` from `:html` it worked great.

Comment: in rails 5 I use `request.format = :json unless request.format.symbol`

Comment: or inline it: ```   before_action { request.format = :json unless request.format } ```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `format.any`:

```
def action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any { render json: your_json, content_type: 'application/json' }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

It's just:

```
render formats: :json
```

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Not quite sure what you mean. This answer is clearly different from other.

Comment: What I mean is that you should add some context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but with '.js' extension. To solve I did the following in the view:

`<%= params.except!(:format) %> 
<%= will_paginate @posts %>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions and it didn't solve my use case.
In some of the controllers of my Rails 4.2 app, there was no explicit `render` called. For example, a service object was called and nothing was returned. Since they are json api controllers, rails was complaining with a missing template error. To resolve I added this to our base controller.

```
  def render(*args)
    options = args.first
    options.present? ? super : super(json: {}, status: :ok)
  end
```

It's a large app I'm converting to Rails 5, so this is just a safety measure as I removed the `RocketPants` gem that seemed to do this automatically.

As a note, my controllers inherit from `ActionController::Base`

Answer (score 0):

I usually put it like this and it works. The lambda symbol ( => ) near :json is important.

```
def greet_action
  msg = {:greet => "hello"}
  render :json => msg
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course:

```
before_filter :always_json

protected

def always_json
  params[:format] = "json"
end
```

You should probably put this in a root controller for your API.