# Rails Template is missing render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

actually i use rails for my REST API, and i need transform my object to json but when i try i got this error:

```
            <h1>Template is missing</h1>
        <p>Missing template firms/show, application/show with {:locale=&gt;[:en], :formats=&gt;[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=&gt;[:erb, :builder, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * &quot;/Users/allan/Desktop/Work/back/app/views&quot;
  * &quot;/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views&quot;
  * &quot;/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views&quot;
  * &quot;/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise_invitable-1.5.5/app/views&quot;
  * &quot;/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.4/app/views&quot;
</p>
```

This is my code

```
 def show
        firm= Firm.find_by_subdomain(params[:subdomain])
        if firm.present?
          respond_to do |format|
            @firm = firm
            format.json { render :json => @firm.to_json }
          end
        end
      end
```

I hope someone here can help me :)

Solve:

```
  def show
    render json: Firm.find_by_subdomain(current_subdomain)
  end
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Template missing means that you asking for a html view, not doing a json request.

If you want to always return json format regardless of format param, do this:

```
before_action :set_default_response_format

protected

def set_default_response_format
  request.format = :json
end
```

@source: [Rails 4 - How to render JSON regardless of requested format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946630/rails-4-how-to-render-json-regardless-of-requested-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.json` at the end of you query when querying your route. Without this, it will try to render `html` and it will go search for view file that might not be present in your case.