# Respond with json format to all formats requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Im implementing a Rest API on Ruby on Rails. So i want to respond to all requests in json format. I made this:

```
include ActionController::MimeResponds


before_filter :force_json

def force_json
  response.format = "json"
  #also tried
  # response.content_type = Mime[:json]
end
```

Those two ways didn't worked. It gives me an html page with errors.
Also is there a way to implement this for the whole api and not for each class?
Thanks!

Comment: checkout the answer specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946630/rails-4-how-to-render-json-regardless-of-requested-format

Comment: While you most certainly *can* respond to all requests in json format, what you *should* do is that block any requests that do not request JSON as a format. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3679735/476712 illustrates how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to happen application wide, you can do something like this in the application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :force_json

  def force_json
     request.format = :json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `responders` gem, you can define this at the top of your class:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  ...
```

Then this controller will respond using JSON by default.

Comment: Even using this gem and adding that code, if i request Content-Type text/html i get an html site. I want to get an error json