# can I use rabl without using .json in the url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, rabl

I have rabl up and running.

I have this in routes:

```
get 'biblios/collection/:biblio_urn' => 'biblios#biblio_rabl', as: 'collection_biblio'
```

in the controller:

```
def biblio_rabl
    biblio = Biblio.where(biblio_urn: params[:biblio_urn]).take     
end
```

This url points to the correct result :

```
http://localhost:3000/dts/biblios/collection/urn:cts:froLit:ed_desmarez:1900
```

I would like that url to always respond using rabl and showing the the template `dts/biblios/biblio_rabl.json.rabl`

I mean *without adding .json* at the end of the url.

I have tried this in the `routes.rb`, but it doesn't redirect :

```
get 'biblios/collection/:biblio_urn' => 'biblios#biblio_rabl', as: 'collection_biblio', to: redirect('biblios/collection/%{biblio_urn}.json')
```

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 - How to render JSON regardless of requested format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946630/rails-4-how-to-render-json-regardless-of-requested-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the response to be json by changing the request format in the controller:

```
request.format = :json
```

Then make sure you have a `respond_to` block like this because it's always better to be explicit about your responses:

```
def biblio_rabl
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { json: Biblio.where(biblio_urn: params[:biblio_urn]).take }
  end
end
```